# XAMPP Installation - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

I'm installing XAMPP on my machine. I'm following Derek Banas youtube tutorial, and I also tried myself, but I'm constantly running into the same issues.

I have changed my Apache ports to 1234 (main), and 8181 (SSL) and MySQL ports to (3307). Apache runs fine, but when I run MySQL from the XAMPP control panel it get this error log.

> 23:11:36  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 23:11:36  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 23:11:36  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 23:11:36  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 23:11:36  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 23:11:36  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 23:11:36  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums.

I have also deleted files from the MySQL folder in the xampp folder recommended in a previous stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/9182716

Also when trying to navigate to localhost phpmyadmin I'm prompted with this warning screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifgUi.jpg

Comment: please update your question with your my.cnf file contents, mysql version number.

Comment: Did you make the necessary firewall exceptions in your windows firewall?

Comment: @fyrye MySQL version is 5.7. I can't find the cnf file. I wasn't prompted to make a firewall change?

Comment: In windows the default paths in order are `C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf`

Comment: If phpmyadmin says access denied, then a mysql is running on your computer. You may have multiple mysql instances installed. But this question has nothing to do with programming, this is purely an admin question.

Comment: I installed MYSQL previously along with work bench ect. That could be the issue. I'll try in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. If changing MySQL port doesn't solve the issue, which was my case. Simply copy the files in xampp/mysql/backup to xampp/mysql/data. Replace any conflicting files and leave the rest.

Then restart Apache and MySQL from the Xampp control panel.

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled and re-installed XAMPP and then went to msconfig and Reduced the UAC to "Never Notify me " and then went back and refreshed mysql on XAMPP. It worked!

Comment: You can't just disable User Account Control to fix a problem on your Xamp configuration. Otherwise, I think the problem was fixed during the reinstallation not because you turned off UAC.